# Sorting JS variables relative to another variable

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to sort a list of Javascript variables. I want them to be sorted relative to another variable. e.g.

```
var val1 = 1;
var val2 = 4;
var val3 = 13;
var val4 = 19;
var val5 = 42;
var sort = 15;
```

I am looking for a script which will sort these variables from the closest variable (val1-5) to the sort variable. The result would end up something like this:

13
15
19
...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't sort variables. Use an array.

Comment: `[1, 4, 13, 19, 42].sort((a, b) => Math.abs(sort - a) - Math.abs(sort - b))`

Comment: *I am looking for a script* Thats not what SO is about. We help fix your code.

Comment: Use arrays and then run the sort function provided implicitly in library.

Answer (score 0):

Like shmosel said, put them in an array first then you can sort them.

```
const sort = 15;
let arr = [1, 4, 13, 19, 42, 15].sort((a, b) => a - b);
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(sort) - 1, 3);
```

Comment: This is a suggestion. Unless we know for sure, this is what OP is looking, I would not recommend answering